# I want to check if the user is logged in on other PC in PHP

Tags: php, session, logging, authorization

I have simple question. I have written system of authorization and I want to save any session in database because I want to write the chat and information about the last logged users. Save the session is very simple and when the user click on the logout update the record with end time is simple too, but sometimes user doesn't click on the logout but close the tab or close the browser and I think about the script which will be check if the user is active but how can I do it easy?

I don't have any idea how I can check whether session of some user is active or the user have running my site now.

Comment: Use search before posting. What about loop each second some ajax code that will update last user activity and if the last activity in the database is older than 5 seconds for example the system will think the user is offline.

Comment: Yes it would be better if users log out properly, but you can't force it -- what if their network connection goes down or their computer crashes? The simple solution is just allow the session to expire. PHP's default session expiry is 30 minutes; no activity in that time and the session will expire on its own; no logout required.

Answer (score 1):

Apart from the obvious log out button that has to be clicked.
You can't really detect 100% accurately using PHP a log out for any other of the events that you described.
You can write a value on the db every time that they user is performing an action of your site e.g last_activity_datetime and after x time if there is no activity assume a log out (would be good to match your session max life time)

Answer (score 1):

The only way to keep track of a user as the leave the page is to keep a constant connection with the client. If you really need to get the exact time of the login/logout look into node.js with socket.io - you can remain connected with the client until they navigate away from the page. This may be overkill for what you are trying to do, but if you plan to add something like chat in the future, node.js would be a very useful option. it can run along side your main web server and they can communicate with each-other to share information. I use it on my website to propagate events and notifications to other users.